# Reactjs: Trying to filter through the array so I can display the stations bases on genre

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and trying to get multiple rows on the frontend in which I can display stations based on genre.

Can someone look to my code what I should do in order to get this working ok.

My PropTypes:

```
static propTypes = {
  stations: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      genre: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      pictureLarge: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
  ).isRequired,
};
```

Creating the array of genres from the json file:

```
const genreArray = [];
const genre = this.props.stations.map(item => item.genre);

genre.map(item => {
  if (genreArray.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    genreArray.push(item);
  }
});
```

Rendering the arrays:

```
return (
  <div className={s.root}>
    <div className={s.container}>
      {genreArray.map(genreName =>
        <section className={s.grid}>

          <div className={s.genreTitle}>
            <h2>
              {genreName}
            </h2>
          </div>,
          {this.props.stations.map(item =>
            <article key={item.id} className={cx(s.cell, s.cellTwoDesktop)}>
              <div className={s.card}>
                <img
                  className={s.thumbnail}
                  src={item.pictureLarge}
                  alt={item.name}
                />
              </div>
            </article>,
          )}
        </section>,
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

So can someone give me a hint how I can filter the stations based on genre so with every subtitle I have stations.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: SO is a place where you can receive help with a blocking problem.  Asking others to write code for you is not the purpose.

Comment: My question is that I can't make it work to filter the stations based on genre. Spend all day on it but don't know how to do it.

Comment: @gravityplanx I don't ask anyone to write my code, I only ask for a hint how to solve this.

Comment: see below @gravityplanx I am glad there are people willing to answer in a normal way.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps ;)

```
var genre = stations.map(item => item.genre); 

const stationsByGenre = genre.map(item => {
  if (genreArray.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    genreArray.push(item);

    //Genre Title - item

    stations.filter(station => {
      return station.genre === item
    }).map(station => {
      //Station row
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Mevan for your tip.

It helped me a lot to solve this puzzle as I was stuck. I will share my solution here:

I created the following constants

```
const genreArray = [];
const stations = this.props.stations;
const genre = stations.map(item => item.genre);
```

Than I searched for the uinique genres and added them to the empty array:

```
genre.map(item => {
  if (genreArray.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    genreArray.push(item);
  }
});
```

After that I was able to add the code as follow:

```
{genreArray.map(genreName =>
        <section className={s.grid} key={genreName}>
          <div className={s.genreTitle}>
            <h2>
              {genreName}
            </h2>
          </div>

          {stations
            .filter(station => {
              return station.genre === genreName;
            })
            .map(station =>
              <article
                key={station.id}
                className={cx(s.cell, s.cellTwoDesktop)}
              >
                <div className={s.card}>
                  <img
                    className={s.thumbnail}
                    src={station.pictureLarge}
                    alt={station.name}
                  />
                </div>
              </article>,
            )}
        </section>,
      )}
```